# Array Type - Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, types

I have question about array Type declaration. I want make array with type Vampire, then I want change population with amount and add one Vampire to vampireMonster array. If I use Vampire type I must make enum for this type?

```
class Vampire: Monster {
var vampireMonster:[Vampire?] = []


override func terrorizetown() {
    if (town?.population)! > 0 {
        town?.changePopulation(amount: -1)
        vampireMonster.append(Vampire)
        super.terrorizetown()
    } else {
        print("Town don't have residents")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to append a `Vampire` *instance* to your array, so you need to call an initialiser of `Vampire`.

Comment: Ok I make something like this and its work, is this correct way?:
vampireMonster.append(Vampire.init())

Comment: You should also not make an array of optional Vampire.  It just doesn't make sense.  Just change to `var vampireMonster = [Vampire]()` to create an empty array.

Comment: `(town?.population)!` doesn't make much sense. If you're going to force unwrap anyway, just go for `town!.population`

Comment: If I make array vampireMonster = [Vampire]() , what kind of argument I must add in vampireMonster.append()